# SSL warning icon - how to get rid of it

Tags: ssl, html, security

I installed my SSL certificate yesterday. However I get the SSL warning (triangle) icon. The excuse for that is that "the page includes other resources which are not secure".

I am not sure what that means but my assumption is that it has something to do with some text inputs which are not secure.

Any information or resources to make me understand more and figure out how to secure everything will be helpful. I don't like the warning there (especially on the signup page) and need to figure out what's the issue. Thanks.

Comment: This topic was discussed on StackOverflow a zillion of times.

Answer (score 7):

You need to make sure not to embed any resources via `http://` - use only `https://`.

If you embed external resources which are available via both HTTP and HTTPS, you can use protocol-relative URLs such as `//domain.tld/whatever` - they'll be loaded over the protocol that's currently used.